# How to use PaperClip to retrieve an image over HTTPS using RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I have an application which stores and retrieves images from Amazons `AWS`.

In order to do that I'm using paperclip.

I use an SSL certification for my application and so require all calls to use HTTPS.

In order to get an image from Amazon `AWS` I do the following:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 shopHeader">
  <img class="img-responsive center-block" widith="150px" height="100px" src=<%= @shop.image.url(:original, timestamp:false) %>>
</div>
```

And when the page loads calls an URL such as  http://cardapiopsbrasil.s3.amazonaws.com/original/shop/221

Instead I need to use HTTPS by generating a link such as https://cardapiopsbrasil.s3.amazonaws.com/original/shop/221

However I'm receiving some warnings such as:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://cardapioalfenas.com.br/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://cardapiopsbrasil.s3.amazonaws.com/original/shop/221'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Is there any way to tell Paperclip or my application to use HTTPS calls to get these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theres an option for `has_attached_file` in your model that specifies the protocol to use

```
# app/models/shop.rb
has_attached_file :image,
                  storage: :s3,
                  s3_protocol: :https #specify the protocol as https
```

the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/S3) explains the various options